# The name does not exist in the current context. Not seeing class

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# coding, so this may be very simple.  In my Site.Master.cs, I have the following code:

```
GetLoggedInUserProperties();
lblLoginUser.Text = string.Format("Welcome {0}", Session[SessionVars.UserName]);
```

In a class file, I have put the following in a Public Class:

```
void GetLoggedInUserProperties()
    {
        string sLoginId = Program.ExtractUserName(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]);
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionVars.LoginId] = sLoginId;

        VerifyInAD(sLoginId);
    }
```

There are no errors in the class file, but my Site.Master.cs cannot find the code in the class file.

I am sure there is a better way to do this, so feel free to let me know.  Also, the lblLoginUser does not seem to work either.  It has the same error. I have tried recreating the label and deleting the designer file (which never came back).  Not sure if this is related or not.

Thank you.

Comment: The simplest way to make this work is to make that method `static` and then call it using `ClassName.GetLoggedInUserProperties()`, where `ClassName` is the name of your class.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding. You have `GetLoggedInUserProperties` as a method inside of a public class? If it is `public static`, you can call the method by `ClassName.GetLoggedInUserProperties()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your methods `public` or `protected` to be visible from the markup. So if you want to reference `GetLoggedInUserProperties()` from the markup, you'll need to change your method declaration to something like this.

```
protected void GetLoggedInUserProperties()
{
}
```

Comment: I used Public and that worked.  Protected did not.  I swear I tried Public before, but this worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make your method public

Here your class

```
public class ClassName
 {
       public void GetLoggedInUserProperties()
       {

       }

 }

public MainWindow()
{
                InitializeComponent();
                ClassName instance = new ClassName();
                instance.GetLoggedInUserProperties();

}
```

Or make your class `static` and call your method :

```
  public static class ClassName
   {
       public static void GetLoggedInUserProperties()
       {

       }

    }



 public MainWindow()
  {
                InitializeComponent();
                ClassName.GetLoggedInUserProperties();

   }
```